# How to retrieve a webpage's title using the command-line?

Tags: command-line, web

I'm looking for a command-line program that prints the title of a webpage.
For instance:

```shell
title-fetcher 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc'
```

...should give:

```
Why Are Bad Words Bad?
```

You give  the URL, the program prints out the title.

Comment: When I download that title I get: "Why Are Bad Words Bad? - Youtube", do you want the "- Youtube" truncated too?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' |
  perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title/si'
```

You can pipe it to GNU `recode` if there are things like `&lt;` in it:

```
wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' |
  perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title/si' |
  recode html..
```

To remove the  `- youtube` part:

```
wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' |
 perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)(?: - youtube)?\s*<\/title/si'
```

---

To point out some of the limitations:

#### portability

There is no standard/portable command to do HTTP queries. A few decades ago, I would have recommended `lynx -source` instead here. But nowadays, `wget` is more portable as it can be found by default on most GNU systems (including most Linux-based desktop/laptop operating systems). Other fairly portables ones include the `GET` command that comes with `perl`'s libwww that is often installed, `lynx -source`, and to a lesser extent `curl`. Other *common* ones include `links -source`, `elinks -source`, `w3m -dump_source`, `lftp -c cat`...

#### HTTP protocol and redirection handling

`wget` may not get the same page as the one that for instance `firefox` would display. The reason being that HTTP servers may choose to send a different page based on the information provided in the request sent by the client.

The request sent by wget/w3m/GET... is going to be different from the one sent by firefox. If that's an issue, you can alter `wget` behaviour to change the way it sends the request though with options.

The most important ones here in this regard are:

- `Accept` and `Accept-language`: that tells the server in which language and charset the client would like to get the response in. `wget` doesn't send any by default so the server will typically send with its default settings. `firefox` on the other end is likely configured to request your language.
- `User-Agent`: that identifies the client application to the server. Some sites send different content based on the client (though that's mostly for differences between javascript language interpretations) and may refuse to serve you if you're using a *robot*-type user agent like `wget`.
- `Cookie`: if you've visited this site before, your browser may have permanent cookies for it. `wget` will not.

`wget` will follow the redirections when they are done at the HTTP protocol level, but since it doesn't look at the content of the page, not the ones done by javascript or things like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">`.

#### Performance/Efficiency

Here, out of laziness, we have `perl` read the whole content in memory before starting to look for the `<title>` tag. Given that the title is found in the `<head>` section that is in the first few bytes of the file, that's not optimal. A better approach, if GNU `awk` is available on your system could be:

```
wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' |
  gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v RS='</title' 'RT{gsub(/.*<title[^>]*>/,"");print;exit}'
```

That way, awk stops reading after the first `</title`, and by exiting, causes `wget` to stop downloading.

#### Parsing of the HTML

Here, `wget` writes the page as it downloads it. At the same time, `perl`, slurps its output (`-0777 -n`) whole in memory and then prints the HTML code that is found between the first occurrences of `<title...>` and `</title`.

That will work for most HTML pages that have a `<title>` tag, but there are cases where it won't work.

By contrast [coffeeMug's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103254/22565) will parse the HTML page as XML and return the corresponding value for `title`. It is more correct *if the page is guaranteed to be valid XML*. However, HTML is not required to be valid XML (older versions of the language were not), and because most browsers out there are lenient and will accept incorrect HTML code, there's even a lot of incorrect HTML code out there.

Both my solution and [coffeeMug's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103254/22565) will fail for a variety of corner cases, sometimes the same, sometimes not.

For instance, mine will fail on:

```
<html><head foo="<title>"><title>blah</title></head></html>
```

or:

```
<!-- <title>old</title> --><title>new</title>
```

While his will fail on:

```
<TITLE>foo</TITLE>
```

(valid html, not xml) or:

or:

```
<title>...</title>
...
<script>a='<title>'; b='</title>';</script>
```

(again, valid `html`, missing `<![CDATA[` parts to make it valid XML).

```
<title>foo <<<bar>>> baz</title>
```

(incorrect html, but still found out there and supported by most browsers)

#### interpretation of the code inside the tags.

That solution outputs the raw text between `<title>` and `</title>`. Normally, there should not be any HTML tags in there, there may possibly be comments (though [not handled by some browsers like firefox](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/1999Nov/0002.html) so very unlikely). There may still be some HTML encoding:

```
$ wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJDhmlMQT60' |
  perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title/si'
Wallace &amp; Gromit - The Cheesesnatcher Part 1 (claymation) - YouTube
```

Which is taken care of by GNU `recode`:

```
$ wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJDhmlMQT60' |
  perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title/si' |
   recode html..
Wallace & Gromit - The Cheesesnatcher Part 1 (claymation) - YouTube
```

But a web client is also meant to do more transformations on that code when displaying the title (like condense some of the blanks, remove the leading and trailing ones). However it's unlikely that there'd be a need for that. So, as in the other cases, it's up to you do decide whether it's worth the effort.

#### Character set

Before UTF-8, iso8859-1 used to be the *preferred* charset on the web for non-ASCII characters though strictly speaking they had to be written as `&eacute;`. More recent versions of HTTP and the HTML language have added the possibility to specify the character set in the HTTP headers or in the HTML headers, and a client can specify the charsets it accepts. UTF-8 tends to be the default charset nowadays.

So, that means that out there, you'll find `é` written as `&eacute;`, as `&#233;`, as UTF-8 `é`, (0xc3 0xa9), as iso-8859-1 (0xe9), with for the 2 last ones, sometimes the information on the charset in the HTTP headers or the HTML headers (in different formats), sometimes not.

`wget` only gets the raw bytes, it doesn't care about their meaning as characters, and it doesn't tell the web server about the preferred charset.

`recode html..` will take care to convert the `&eacute;` or `&#233;` into the proper sequence of bytes for the character set used on your system, but for the rest, that's trickier.

If your system charset is utf-8, chances are it's going to be alright most of the time as that tends to be the default charset used out there nowadays.

```
$ wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if82MGPJEEQ' |
 perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title/si'
Noir Désir - L&#39;appartement - YouTube
```

That `é` above was a UTF-8 `é`.

But if you want to cover for other charsets, once again, it would have to be taken care of.

It should also be noted that this solution won't work at all for UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoded pages.

#### To sum up

Ideally, what you need here, is a real web browser to give you the information. That is, you need something to do the HTTP request with the proper parameters, intepret the HTTP response correctly, fully interpret the HTML code as a browser would, and return the title.

As I don't think that can be done on the command line with the browsers I know (though see now [this trick with `lynx`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103352/22565)), you have to resort to heuristics and approximations, and the one above is as good as any.

You may also want to take into consideration performance, security... For instance, to cover all the cases (for instance, a web page that has some javascript pulled from a 3rd party site that sets the title or redirect to another page in an onload hook), you may have to implement a real life browser with its dom and javascript engines that may have to do hundreds of queries for a single HTML page, some of which trying to exploit vulnerabilities...

While [using regexps to parse HTML is often frowned upon](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), here is a typical case where it's good enough for the task (IMO).

Comment: Does it download the images from the pages too? Also will it leave junk html files behind?

Comment: I don't understand "You pipe to to recode html.. if there are things like &lt; in it.", can you give examples please? Thanks.

Comment: Ufoguy: No, just the html

Comment: That Brazilian Guy:  pipe is a basic unix concept, tl dr too explain here.  Basically you send the output to the next command instead of the screen.  recode is a program to recode stuff

Comment: recode works on files so you get the output 'piped' (saved) in a file and then you use recode on it.  I had to install record with apt-get.

Comment: You probably want to terminate the title at the first instance of `<` since titles are not guaranteed to have end tags and any other tag should force its termination. You may also want to strip new lines.

Comment: This didn't return anything for me when I ran it. Is it working for others? wget ver: 1.12, Perl ver: v5.14.0. It literally returns nothing and drops to a new prompt. I think the issue is with `wget`. If I run it without the pipe I get binary data dumped to the console.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 12.10, so something changed with `wget` at some point. wget ver: 1.13.4

Comment: It is not recommended to use regular expressions to parse HTML. Ever. Not even in this case. It's a bad habit. Use a real parser instead. There is a famous humorous Stackoverflow answer about this...

Comment: @RobinGreen That post was about using regex to parse a non-regular language. There are caveats, but this is a problem that is easily reduced to a regular language. I recommend using regex to parse HTML. Sometimes. In this case.

Comment: Does `wget` support Unicode?

Comment: @BrianNickel, even firefox doesn't support a title without the end tag, so I wouldn't bother covering for that.

Comment: @RobinGreen, you need an HTML browser, here. An XML parser is going to be a worse heuristic than my regexp one.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas HTML parsers exist, I did not say XML parser. There are about thousands of different languages that can be parsed, XML is only one of them!

Comment: @RobinGreen: and the number of HTML parsers that work for almost everything is approximately 3.

Comment: And the number of regular expressions that work for almost everything is approximately 0.

Comment: What does the `..` mean at the end of `| recode html..` ?

Comment: Ok, so the `..` is just a more explicitly saying that `html` is the **input** encoding http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/recode-doc/Tutorial.html#Tutorial

Answer (score 28):

You can also try `hxselect` (from [HTML-XML-Utils](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/)) with `wget` as follows:

```
wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' | hxselect -s '\n' -c  'title' 2>/dev/null
```

You can install `hxselect` in Debian based distros using: 
 `sudo apt-get install html-xml-utils`.

STDERR redirection is to avoid the `Input is not well-formed. (Maybe try normalize?)` message.

In order to get rid of "- YouTube", pipe the output of the above command to `awk '{print substr($0, 0, length($0)-10)}'`.

Comment: "hxselect" does'nt seem to be installed on Ubuntu by default. I'm even unable to find it in my existing repositories. How do I install it?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install html-xml-utils`

Comment: I get this error on Ubuntu 12.10 "Input is not well-formed. (Maybe try normalize?)"

Comment: You'll likely want to add `-i` to `hxselect` too for the same reasons that manatwork mentioned in my A, otherwise it won't match `<TITLE>`.

Comment: I haven't found what to do with the msg. about normalizing the output. No such switch on `hxselect`.

Comment: @slm Just direct the error to `/dev/null`. I guess it is a bug in pop function of `hxselect`.

Comment: For the Mac OS X folks [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) has a formula with hxselect in it. Install with `brew install html-xml-utils`.

Comment: For those getting the "Maybe try normalize?" message try piping the HTML through `hxnormalize -l 3000 -x 2>/dev/null` before piping it through `hxselect`.

Comment: I was having issues with hxselect completely refusing to work on some poorly-structured HTML, so I had to pipe it through hxclean first (e.g. `wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' | hxclean | hxselect -s '\n' -c  'title' 2>/dev/null`).

Answer (score 24):

You can also use `curl` and `grep` to do this. You'll need to enlist the use of [PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)](http://www.pcre.org/) in `grep` to get the look behind and look ahead facilities so that we can find the `<title>...</title>` tags.

#### Example

```
$ curl 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' -so - | \
    grep -iPo '(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)'
Why Are Bad Words Bad? - YouTube
```

#### Details

The `curl` switches:

- `-s` = silent
- `-o -` = send output to STDOUT

The `grep` switches:

- `-i` = case insensitivity
- `-o` = Return only the portion that matches
- `-P` = PCRE mode

The pattern to `grep`:

- `(?<=<title>)` = look for a string that starts with this to the left of it
- `(?=</title>)` = look for a string that ends with this to the right of it
- `(.*)` = everything in between `<title>..</title>`.

#### More complex situations

If `<title>...</titie>` spans multiple lines, then the above won't find it. You can mitigate this situation by using `tr`, to delete any `\n` characters, i.e. `tr -d '\n'`.

#### Example

Sample file.

```
$ cat multi-line.html 
<html>
<title>
this is a \n title
</TITLE>
<body>
<p>this is a \n title</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And a sample run:

```
$ curl 'http://www.jake8us.org/~sam/multi-line.html' -so - | \
     tr -d '\n' | \
     grep -iPo '(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)'
this is a \n title
```

#### lang=...

If the `<title>` is set like this, `<title lang="en">` then you'll need to remove this prior to `grep`ing it. The tool `sed` can be used to do this:

```
$ curl 'http://www.jake8us.org/~sam/multi-line.html' -so - | \
     tr -d '\n' | \
     sed 's/ lang="\w+"//gi' | \
     grep -iPo '(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)'
this is a \n title
```

The above finds the case insensitive string `lang=` followed by a word sequence (`\w+`). It is then stripped out.

#### A real HTML/XML Parser - using Ruby

At some point regex will fail in solving this type of problem. If that occurs then you'll likely want to use a real HTML/XML parser. One such parser is [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). It's available in Ruby as a Gem and can be used like so:

```
$ curl 'http://www.jake8us.org/~sam/multi-line.html' -so - | \
    ruby -rnokogiri -e \
     'puts Nokogiri::HTML(readlines.join).xpath("//title").map { |e| e.content }'

this is a \n title
```

The above is parsing the data that comes via the `curl` as HTML (`Nokogiri::HTML`). The method `xpath` then looks for nodes (tags) in the HTML that are leaf nodes, (`//`) with the name `title`. For each found we want to return its content (`e.content`). The `puts` then prints them out.

#### A real HTML/XML Parser - using Perl

You can also do something similar with Perl and the [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) module.

```
$ cat title_getter.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

$tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_url($ARGV[0]); 
($title = $tree->findvalue('//title')) =~ s/^\s+//;
print $title . "\n";
```

You can then run this script like so:

```
$ ./title_getter.pl http://www.jake8us.org/~sam/multi-line.html
this is a \n title
```

Comment: Neat solution! :)

Comment: @coffeMug - thanks, seemed more straight forward than the other 2 methods.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is not so simple. Tags written as “<TITLE>”, “<title lang=en>”, “<title\n>” will not be matched by your expression. Even bigger problem, neither “<title>\noops\n</title>” will be.

Comment: @manatwork - thanks, true, the case sensitivity can be dealt w/ easily w/ the `-i` switch to `grep`. The other items you noted will definitely be trickier. They could be dealt with but you'll have to deal with them as you run into them. The `\n` could be incorporated into the regex.

Comment: @manatwork - fixed the newline issue & the case sensitivity.

Comment: Attempting to parse html using regex [tends to be frowned upon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) round here.

Comment: @user3490 - it's perfectly fine to do so, assuming you understand the risks!

Comment: The regex could be: `(?<=<title[^>]*>\s*)([^<]*)` which assumes: 1) there can be anything inside the open `<title>` tag, including but not limited to a `lang` attribute. 2) no other tag tag should be inside the `<title></title>` pair.  `[^<]*` might fail for malformed html in which there are tags inside the title, but, on the other hand, works better than `.*` if there are line breaks.

Comment: Note that `-o` is GNU `grep` only. `-P` is only on GNU greps built with PCRE support. `\n` should be converted to space, not removed, `lang` is not the only attribute the `title` tag supports, and the proper syntax is `<title lang="en">` anyway.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks for the feedback, what's the harm in removing `\n`?

Comment: @slm, `<title>Unix\nLinux</title>` is meant to be `Unix Linux`, not `UnixLinux`.

Answer (score 7):

Using simple regex to parse HTML is naive. E.g. with newlines and ignoring special character encoding specified in the file. Do the right thing and really parse the page using any of the other real parsers mentioned in the other answers or use the following one liner:

```
python -c "import bs4, urllib2; print bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/')).title.text"
```

(The above includes a Unicode character).

BeautifulSoup handles a lot of incorrect HTML (e.g. missing closing tags) as well, that would completely throw of simplistic regexing. You can install it in a standard python using:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or if you don't have `pip`, with

```
easy_install beautifulsoup4
```

Some operating systems like Debian/Ubuntu also have it packaged (`python-bs4` package on Debian/Ubuntu).

Comment: `bs4` is not in the python standard library. You have to install it using `easy_install beautfulsoup4` (not `easyinstall bs4`).

Comment: @Anthon included your info

Comment: Prints the `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?` error on Python 3.11.3 / beautifulsoup4-4.12.2-1

Comment: [A more recent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563920/172800) may work, I tested with `python -c "import bs4, urllib2; print bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://example.com')).title.text"`

Answer (score 6):

Simple way:

```
curl -s example.com | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | tail -c+8
```

Few alternatives:

```
curl -s example.com | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | cut -d'>' -f2-
wget -qO- example.com | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Comment: These are the only ones that worked for me!

Comment: All three sadly struggle with characters such as `&` and `"` , displayed as  `&amp;` and `&quot;`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's "cheating" but one option is [pup, a command line HTML parser](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup).

Here are two ways to do it:

Using the `meta` field with  `property="og:title` attribute

```
$ wget -q 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' -O - | \
> pup 'meta[property=og:title] attr{content}'
Why Are Bad Words Bad?
```

and another way using the `title` field directly  (and then lopping off the `- YouTube` string at the end).

```
$ wget -q 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' -O - | \
> pup 'title text{}' | sed 's/ - YouTube$//'
Why Are Bad Words Bad?
```

Comment: To avoid character entities, users may wish to use pup's `--plain` option.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be possible with `lynx` using this trick:

```
lynx 3>&1 > /dev/null -nopause -noprint -accept_all_cookies \
  -cmd_script /dev/stdin<<'EOF' 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc'
set PRINTER=P:printf '%0s\\n' "$LYNX_PRINT_TITLE">&3:TRUE
key p
key Select key
key ^J
exit
EOF
```

Because that's a real life web browser, it doesn't suffer from many of the limitations I mention in my [other answer](/a/103253).

Here, we're using the fact that `lynx` sets the `$LYNX_PRINT_TITLE` environment variable to the title of the current page when printing the page.

Above, we use `lynx` scripting facility (with the script passed on stdin via a heredocument) to:

1. define a lynx "printer" called `P` that just outputs the content of that variable to file descriptor `3` (that file descriptor is redirected to `lynx`'s stdout with `3>&1` while lynx stdout is itself redirected to /dev/null).
2. simulate the user pressing <kbd>p</kbd>, and the <kbd>End</kbd> (aka <kbd>Select</kbd>), and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`^J`).

Answer (score 2):

A Python 3 + BeautifulSoup example might be:

```
python3 -c "import bs4, requests; print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://example.com/').content).title.text)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `htmlq`:

```bash
curl --silent "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc" | htmlq --text title
```

If you do not have it installed, `htmlq` can be built with cargo:

```bash
cargo install htmlq
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked the idea of Stéphane Chazelas to use Lynx and LYNX_PRINT_TITLE, but that script didn't work for me under Ubuntu 14.04.5.

I have made a simplified version of it by using running Lynx and using files pre-configured in advance.

Add the following line to /etc/lynx-cur/lynx.cfg (or wherever your lynx.cfg resides):

```
PRINTER:P:printenv LYNX_PRINT_TITLE>/home/account/title.txt:TRUE:1000
```

This line instructs to save title, while printing, to "/home/account/title.txt" - you may choose any file name you wish. You request VERY large pages, increase the above value from "1000" to any number of lines per page you want, otherwise Lynx will make additional prompt "when printing document containing very large number of pages".

Then create the /home/account/lynx-script.txt file with the following contents:

```
key p
key Select key
key ^J
exit
```

Then run Lynx using the following command-line options:

```
lynx -term=vt100 -display_charset=utf-8 -nopause -noprint -accept_all_cookies -cmd_script=/home/account/lynx-script.txt "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc" >/dev/nul
```

Upon completion of this command, the file /home/account/title.txt will be created with the title of your page.

Long story short, here is a PHP function that returns a page title based on the given URL, or false in case of error.

```
function GetUrlTitle($url)
{
  $title_file_name = "/home/account/title.txt";
  if (file_exists($title_file_name)) unlink($title_file_name); // delete the file if exists
  $cmd = '/usr/bin/lynx -cfg=/etc/lynx-cur/lynx.cfg -term=vt100 -display_charset=utf-8 -nopause -noprint -accept_all_cookies -cmd_script=/home/account/lynx-script.txt "'.$url.'"';
  exec($cmd, $output, $retval);
  if (file_exists($title_file_name))
  {
    $title = file_get_contents($title_file_name);
    unlink($title_file_name); // delete the file after reading
    return $title;
  } else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

print GetUrlTitle("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using nokogiri, one can use a simple CSS-based query to extract the inner text of the  tag:

```
 $ nokogiri -e 'puts $_.at_css("title").content'
 Why Are Bad Words Bad? - YouTube
```

Similarly, to extract the value of the "content" attribute of the  tag:

```
$ nokogiri -e 'puts $_.at_css("meta[name=title]").attr("content")'
Why Are Bad Words Bad?
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Translating the accepted Perl answer (above) to Raku:*

```perl
~$ wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' |
   raku -e 'given slurp() { put $/ if m:g[ \<title .*? \> .+? \<\/title\> ] };'
<title>Why Are Bad Words Bad? - YouTube</title>
```

*OR (same as above, but dropping Tags):*

```perl
~$ wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' |
   raku -e 'given slurp() { put $0 if m[ \<title .*? \> (.+?) \<\/title\> ] };'
Why Are Bad Words Bad? - YouTube
```

Raku's `slurp()` method/function quite literally *slurps* the entire file into memory--newlines and all. In Raku, regex `.` "any-character" *includes* newline, so title-tags spanning multiple lines can be successfully extracted. (There's room for improvement: in Raku using `lines.join(" ")` instead of `slurp()` will effectively translate `\n` newlines to   space, saving a translation step later).

---

*Using Raku's `HTTP::UserAgent` and `HTML::Parser::XML`  module(s):*

```perl
use HTTP::UserAgent;
use HTML::Parser::XML;

#HTTP::UserAgent code:

my $ua-client = HTTP::UserAgent.new(); $ua-client.timeout = 10;
my $response = $ua-client.get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc'); 
die "unsuccessful" unless $response.is-success ;
#say ~$response.header;
#say ~$response.content;

#HTML::Parser::XML code:

my $parser = HTML::Parser::XML.new;
my $xmldoc = $parser.parse($response.content);
for $xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("title") {.contents.put};
```

*Using Raku's `Cro::HTTP::Client` and `HTML::Parser::XML` module(s):*

```perl
use Cro::HTTP::Client;
#use Cro::HTTP::BodyParsers;
use HTML::Parser::XML;

#Cro::HTTP::Client code:

my $client = Cro::HTTP::Client.new(
    headers => [ User-agent => 'Cro'], 
    #add-body-parsers => [ HTML::Parser::XML ],
    );
my $response = await $client.get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc');
#say ~$response;
my Str $body_text1 = await $response.body-text();
#say body-text1;

#HTML::Parser::XML code:

my $parser = HTML::Parser::XML.new;
my $xmldoc = $parser.parse($body_text1);
for $xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("title") {.contents.put};
```

The above two scripts return `Why Are Bad Words Bad? - YouTube` <sup>†</sup>. Both scripts *can* return the desired `title` by converting the content/body to `.Str` and using a Regex (after code at top). However the more elegant/efficient way is to parse the `content`/`body` using an `XML` parser supplied by Raku's `HTML::Parser::XML` module. (Note: the `Cro` version uses Promises to accomplish client requests, and in some cases the `Cro::HTTP::BodyParsers` module can/should be used).

---

Finally, as an alternative to  to `HTML::Parser::XML` parsing of the `$response` (which calls Raku's `XML` module under-the-hood), you can instead use Document Object Model (DOM) parsing with Raku's `DOM::Tiny` module. To either of the scripts above, swap out the add the `HTML::Parser::XML` code, instead adding  `use DOM::Tiny;` line at top, and the following code at bottom:

```perl
use DOM::Tiny;

my $dom = DOM::Tiny.parse($response.content.Str); #Use w/ HTTP::UserAgent script
#OR
my $dom = DOM::Tiny.parse($body_text1); #Use w/ Cro::HTTP::Client script

#THEN
my $title = $dom.at('title').text;
.put for $title;
```

Using the `DOM::Tiny` code, the title-text `Why Are Bad Words Bad? - YouTube` is returned (no Regex required).

---

<sup><sub>†</sub></sup> <sub>The Raku ecosystem has other client modules for HTTP, including `HTTP::Tiny` and `HTTP::Tinyish`.</sub>

https://raku.land/github:sergot/HTTP::UserAgent
https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent
https://raku.land/zef:cro/Cro::HTTP
https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-client
https://raku.land/cpan:HANENKAMP/DOM::Tiny
https://github.com/zostay/raku-DOM-Tiny
https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

Using xidel:

```
$ xidel -s http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc --css title
Why Are Bad Words Bad? - YouTube
```

If necessary, `apt install xidel` or similar.